# Find tag preceding another tag BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

`find_previous` gives the tag preceding a specific tag, but I want to find text in `<b>` tag just above `<table>` tag.

```
"
<h2>Hi</h2>
<b>I am here</b>
<b>Output</b>
<h2>Hi</h2>
<table>
.....
</table>


"
```

The expected output should be `Output`.
How can I do this?

Comment: Please add the code you have so far. Is this the only `<table>` in the HTML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to [`find_previous()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous) can first be used to locate the previous `<b>` tag. From there the text of the element can be extracted using `.text` or `.get_text()`.

With the HTML you have, the following would work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<h2>Hi</h2>
<b>I am here</b>
<b>Output</b>
<h2>Hi</h2>
<table>
.....
</table>"""                

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.table.find_previous('b').text)
```

Which would display the `<b>` tag as:

```
Output
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html ='''
<h2>Hi</h2>
<b>I am here</b>
<b>Output</b>
<h2>Hi</h2>
<table>
.....
</table>
'''               
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
item = soup.select_one("table").find_previous_sibling("b").text
print(item)
```